# How to apply comma separation,strip_tags and orderby to wp_get_object_terms

Tags: terms

I have this...

```
<?php echo strip_tags (get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'school-year-level', ' ',', ')); ?>
```

which nicely unlinks and comma separates a list of terms from a specified custom taxonomy (school-year-level). However the list isn't in the order I want.
I've hunted down this...
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms

```
<?php $product_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'school-year-level', $args );
$args = array('orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
if ( ! empty( $product_terms ) ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $product_terms ) ) {
            foreach( $product_terms as $term ) {
                echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'school-year-level' ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a> '; 
            }
    }
}           
?>
```

but my attempts to 1. make it a comma separated list, and 2. get the `orderby` $args to work 3. `strip_tags` it haven't been working for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of performance, you should rather use `get_the_terms()` to get the post terms and then use `usort` to sort the results. `wp_get_object_terms()` are not cached and therefor requires an extra db call per post queried.

While at it, also, you would want to pass the complete term object to `get_term_link()`. If the term is not cached, and the slug or ID is passed to `get_term_link()`, `get_term_link()` will query the db to get the complete term object, which you already have. Passing the complete term object saves unnecessary db calls or having to look in the term cache for the term object.

Lastly, you should always define `$args` first before using it. In your original code, you are trying to use `$args` first, and then define it, this was the main issue for your failure.

Anyways, you can use the following idea to sort your post terms

```
$product_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'school-year-level' );

// Make sure we have terms and also check for WP_Error object
if (    $product_terms
     && !is_wp_error( $product_terms )
) {
    @usort( $product_terms, function ( $a, $b )
    {
        return strcasecmp( 
            $a->slug,
            $b->slug
        );
    });

    // Display your terms as normal
    $term_list = [];
    foreach ( $product_terms as $term ) 
        $term_list[] = esc_html( $term->name );

    echo implode( ', ', $term_list );
}
```

### EDIT

To make clicable links that link back to the term's archive page, you need to replace

```
$term_list[] = esc_html( $term->name );
```

with

```
$term_list[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
```

Note, if you pass the complete term object to `get_term_link()`, you do not need to pass the taxonomy. The taxonomy is gathered from the term object.

Comment: How would this be edited to include the terms as "linkable"?

Comment: See my **EDIT** ;-)

Comment: Not to split hairs, and while I agree with Pieter's answer in terms of best practices, my answer--the originally accepted--actually answered the question posted.

Comment: @darrinb answering a question is not always about fixing the code in OP, if there is a smarter way to do something which the OP can benefit from (*or for that matter anyone who finds the post*), why not make the OP aware of it. Yes, you've answered the question directly, I just posted a better alternative (*which would be more beneficial*) to what the OP is currently using. The onus still lies with the OP to accept whatever answer he feels is the better approach to him. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (tested on my dev site):

```
$taxonomy = 'name-of-your-taxonomy';
$args = array('orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
$product_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, $args );

if ( ! empty( $product_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $product_terms ) ) {
    $terms = array();
    foreach( $product_terms as $term ) {
        $terms[] = esc_html( $term->name );
    }
    echo join( ', ', $terms );
}
```

Comment: Just a note, `wp_get_object_terms()` results in an extra db call for every post queried, using `get_the_terms()` with `usort()` is better proposition here as it is faster and no extra db queries

Comment: Ooooo! How would you do that? @PieterGoosen

Comment: Just a heads up, get_the_terms() actually calls wp_get_object_terms() if the terms aren't already cached.

Comment: Post terms are always cached unless you have set your query explicitely to not cache post terms (*`update_post_term_cache=false`*), which would be really stupid. In this case, any term related function would make db calls. You would see the difference in db calls when you have some script running to display the amount of db calls made for a specific piece of code ;-)